# How can I output System.currentTimeMillis() to an ADF page?

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

I'm using this and it doesn't work as expected. I'm trying to cache bust a css file as it changes a lot and we can't always expect users to thoroughly clear their cache.

```
  <c:set var="buster" value="{System.currentTimeMillis()}" />
  <af:resource type="css" source="/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/shared/css/maaui.css?r=${buster}"/>
```

Unfortunately that renders

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" afrres="true" href="/myAccount/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/shared/css/maaui.css?r=%7BSystem.currentTimeMillis()%7D">
```

It doesn't execute the method. I tried `${}` and `#{}` as well and neither seem to work for me.
Can anyone help me to achieve the desired result? Basically a random string that will change each time a user visits a page.  I can easily do this in .NET but I am very new to Oracle ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<c:set var="buster" value="{myBean.time}" />

<af:resource type="css" source="/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/shared/css/maaui.css?r=#{buster}"/>
```

And in MyBean managed backing bean

```
public long getTime()
{
return System.getCurrentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: yes I did something quite similar and it worked great. Thanks!